# How to "import" xdebug into existing php docker container

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, phpstorm, xdebug

I have a `docker-compose.yml` with a php container that already exists insid::

```
version: "2"

services:
  php:
     image: wodby/drupal-php:5.6-3.3.1
     environment:
       PHP_SENDMAIL_PATH: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -S mailhog:1025
       PHP_FPM_CLEAR_ENV: "no"
       DB_HOST: mariadb
       DB_USER: drupal
       DB_PASSWORD: drupal
       DB_NAME: drupal
       DB_DRIVER: mysql
     volumes:
       - docker-sync:/var/www/html
```

I need to install xdebug onto the docker container so that I can then use it with PHPStorm.

A lot of tutorials ar using a `Dockerfile` is needed to create a php image with xdebug on it. I have not used docker for more than hosting my project locally so I am confused to how the Dockerfile comes into play and if you can use a Dockerfile with a docker-compose file as well.

Does anyone know the steps I need to take in order to add xdebug to this existing container

I am using the following stack: https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/Wodby/drupal-php/issues/1#issuecomment-250981261

Comment: oh man, if it is actually that simple that would be amazing

Comment: Did it work DenverCoder9?

Comment: I do not recall specifically but it got me on the right track